# asp.net c# data to a database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, database-connection, asp.net-4.5

I have been at this for two days now with no luck. 
The problem is I am trying to input data into my sql server database via a web form. every time I try to run I am getting errors .

**Bellow is the Error I am Getting when I run the code**
[image: Error Image]

**this is the code for the web form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = SQLEXSPRESS; Initial Catalog = OMS; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter ();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer tbl (FirstName,LastName) Customer VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)", cs);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname.Text;

            cs.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Error occurs here
            cs.Close();
        }

        protected void firstname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void lastname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**This is my database Table code**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
[CustomerID] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[LastName]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Address]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[City]       VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
[Postcode]   VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[Country]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Modified]   ROWVERSION   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC)
```

);

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At a rough guess I'd say your connection string was wrong.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking but the connection string  SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = SQLEXSPRESS; Initial Catalog = OMS; Integrated Security = true"); should be ok. I dont know what else it could be.

Comment: Your query it should be INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = SQLEXSPRESS; Initial Catalog = OMS; Integrated Security = true");
```

Should be

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = OMS; Integrated Security = true");
```

You spelt express wrong!

You might also need to use Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Thank you Andrew, Data Source = SQLEXPRESS is still not working. when I try Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS i get a error saying Unrecognised seascape sequence. any idea how to get around that ?

Comment: I am presuming you mean escape and not seascape :) ....anyhow @"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS..." should fix it.

Comment: Also the other comment about your query being wrong is valid as well and that will need to be fixed.